# When is the planned date for C++0x to be released into the wild?

Tags: c++, c++11

We've been waiting forever to see if it's going to become a full-fledged language, and yet there doesn't seem to be a release of the formal definition. Just committees and discussions and revising.

Does anyone know of a planned deadline for C++0x, or are we going to have to start calling it C++1x?

Comment: Gonna be C++Forever

Comment: Even when the final spec is released, it's going to take a while to port a lot of useful libraries over. It's fairly backwards compatible, but not 100%

Comment: and it's going to take a while to get compliant compilers as well.

Comment: Where does it loses compatibility?

Comment: I don't think it loses compatibility as it's mostly adding features with different syntax (strong typed enums) and losing restrictions (unrestricted unions).

Comment: From wikipedia: However, according to the announcement made by Bjarne Stroustrup, ..., the new standard will be "almost 100-percent compatible with the existing Standard C++".

Comment: @jalf: It will take a long time to get all compilers fully-compliant (when, GCC, when will you finish C99?). But Microsoft are going to be aggressive with MSVC (well, Sutter is), and I would not be in the least surprised if Comeau get something out very quickly too. Both already offer significant or full draft C++0x language support, and it's not as if the final spec is going to have any huge surprises for people on the standards body. The Boost folks will be in with final-spec libraries asap.

Comment: i bet clang will be the first c++ compiler supporting it =) If you look at the speed of its development these days, you can only be impressed :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well the committee is currently very busy working on the next revision - every meeting is prefaced by many papers, that are a good indicator of the effort that is going into the new standard: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/

What is a little concerning (but reassuring in the sense that they will not rush publishing a standard just to assuage the public, yet do sense the urgency involved) is that Stroustrup just put out a paper saying that we need to take a second look at concepts and make sure that they are as simple as can be - and has proposed a reasonable solution.
[Edit] For those who are interested, this paper is available at: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2906.pdf.

C++0x will be a huge improvement upon C++ in many regards, and while I do not speak for the committee - my hope is that it will happen by late 2010.

[Edit] As underscored by one of the commenters, it is worth appreciating that there is significant concern amongst a few committee members that either the quality of the standard or the schedule (late 2010) will have to suffer if concepts are included: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2893.pdf.  But whether these concerns will be substantiated is worth being patient about - we will have more information about this once the committee concludes its meeting in Frankfurt this july (the post-meeting mailing can be expected in late-july, early august).

Personally, i sense that it would not be a huge loss to get the standard out without concepts (maintain the late 2010 schedule), and then add them as a TR - versus rushing them through even when there is palpable uneasiness amongst the more seasoned committee members (about concepts) - but I will defer to the committee here - while they have never claimed or been described as perfect, the majority of them are far more qualified to make these decisions than I am and deserve some of our confidence if history is any indicator - I would err on the side of trusting their instincts (over mine) assuming there was some reasonable consensus amongst them.

For some perspective, and so that one does not despair about these obstacles too much, compare this to what happened within the ecmascript community - Brendan Eich, the creator, had some very different design goals for the next revision of ecmascript (es5) from some of the other similarly talented wizards in the ecmascript community - they had multiple meetings and after much discussion (some of it heated ;) formulated a very very reasonable compromise followed by a frenzy of activity that has resulted in ecmascript 5 (all in the span of 1-2 years, including the conflict) which will be an excellent and pragmatic, yet much more conservative than Eich had initially proposed, revision of javascript. I have similar hopes for C++ (acknowledging that C++ is a much much much larger language - but then much more effort has been put in ;)

Comment: concepts seem to be the show-stopper currently :( This is an interesting paper about the issue: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2893.pdf the long pole gets longer :(

Comment: yes - the issue with concepts is definitely concerning - but i think good will come from it - even if they don't deliver it in the next version of the C++ standard, with 3-5 year cycles, we'll get to play with them soon enough ;)

Comment: Here's the paper I assume Faisal was referring to: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2906.pdf - I just read it, interesting stuff, but it also made me a lot more skeptical about the idea of concepts. It seems like unless they're extremely careful, it could pretty much destroy generic programming, or at least bring the standard badly out of sync with actual users of the language.

Comment: I wish they would pull concepts and ship.  There are other features which I feel are just as important:  new memory model, auto, lambdas, variadic templates.  I think each of these individually will help "average" users more than concepts every will.  Shipping a smaller standard also means that compilers have a achievable target std now.  This will hopefully reduce the chance of what happend to C++98 where it took 10 years before you could use 99% of C++ features more or less in a portable way.

Comment: The next meeting is in frankfurt next month. Let's build up a SO-group and demonstrate "concepts out!" there =)

Comment: heh heh - i'm all about standing up against power structures gone wrong - but i'd like to give the committee some space here (at least initially ;) - i find stroustrup (based on his writings) to be a mostly pragmatic person - and I have reasonable confidence in some of the other wizards (based on their books, and writings too) who attend those meetings - so i'm holding on to hope (how ever misplaced the rest of you may think it might be ;)

Comment: Count me in as another vote for dropping concepts. They're so huge, it's almost like adding C++/CLI (okay, maybe not that huge).

Answer (score 4):

FTR: C++11 [has been approved by ISO on 12 August 2011](http://herbsutter.com/2011/08/12/we-have-an-international-standard-c0x-is-unanimously-approved/).

Answer (score 0):

Around 200A or 200B. If you remember the Y2K problem, these are years 199K and 199L ... oops wait, K and L aren't hex digits. Boom!

Answer (score 0):

[Slashdot posted a story](http://tech.slashdot.org/story/09/07/23/1817225/Stroustrup-Says-New-C-Standard-Delayed-Until-2010-Or-Later) of an interview with Bjarne Stroustrup, and in it, he drops the bombsheel that the release has been delayed until 2010 or later:

[No C++0x, Long Live C++1x](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/218600111) (Page 3)!